# When I post back to my controller all values for my model are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have cut the model back to one field:

//Model

```
public class LetterViewModel
{
    public string LetterText;
}
```

//Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new LetterViewModel();
    model.LetterText = "Anything";

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LetterViewModel model)
{ 
    //model.LetterText == null
    return View(model);
}
```

//view

```
@model Test.Models.LetterViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Create a Letter";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="Bottom">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.LetterText)
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

When I check the Network tab in dev tools it is showing the value entered is being included in the request.  However, when the HttpPost controller is fired the field is empty.

Comment: what you got in post methods paramater i.e. model?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: just debugg your post method and what value comes in post methods parameter? is it null?

Comment: When I type "Test" into the field and submit the form I can see the request object in dev tools contains LetterText: Test however when I put a break point on the code in the HttpPost controller, I get model.LetterText = null.

Comment: mention action and controller name with post request in begin form and then try.

Comment: Gave this a try: did not work :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` does not set the value of fields, only properties. You need to change you model to include properties

```
public class LetterViewModel
{
    public string LetterText { get; set; } // add getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a custom binder instead of the default binder in cases where you don't have the option to convert fields to properties.

Loop through the form inputs and set them using reflection. `MemberInformation` is my class but you can just use `FieldInfo`.

This doesn't do an object graph but if I need that ability I'll enhance my answer. The tuple in the `foreach` uses c# 7.0. It also assumes that you saved your object from the previous `GET` before this `POST`.

```
using CommonBusinessModel.Metadata;
using GHCOMvc.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AtlasMvcWebsite.Binders
{
  public class FieldModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
  {
    // this runs before any filters (except auth filters)
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
      Type type = typeof(GHCOBusinessModel.GHCOPPAType);
      AtlasKernelBusinessModel.VersionedObject instance = PolicyController.Policy;

      foreach ((var value, var member) in (from string input in form
                                           let fi = type.GetField(input)
                                           where fi != null
                                           let mi = new MemberInformation(fi, instance)
                                           where !mi.ReadOnly
                                           select (form[input], mi)))
        member.SetValue(value);

      return instance;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add [FromBody] before parameter to Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody]LetterViewModel model)
{ 
    //model.LetterText == null
    return View(model);
}
```