# Model not null, but children objects are null

Tags: binding, asp.net-mvc-5

on postback, my model exists but it's child object `Policy` is null.

What am I doing wrong?

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Wizard([Bind(Include = "Policy")] InformationModel model, Directions direction)
{
   return View(model);
}
```

**Model**

```cs
public class InformationModel
{
    public GHCOPPAType Policy;
}
```

**View**

```cs
@model GHCOMvc.Models.InformationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Wizard", "Policy", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Policy.Id)

    <button class="btn btn-success" name="direction" value="Next">Next</button>
}
```

Comment: I was using fields instead of properties

Comment: I provided a new answer on the duplicate having to do with custom model binding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626575/when-i-post-back-to-my-controller-all-values-for-my-model-are-null/43372139#43372139